# query with if and count

Tags: php, mysql

trying to add if condition to do the following

1- selecting data depending on if that data selected before by the user

2- selecting data depending on how many time that data was selected by all users

3- setting maximum number of how many times the data could be selected by all user

here is my current code as you can see all that i made the first condition and it work fine

```
$sql=mysql_query(

"SELECT  courseid,coursename
FROM newcourses 
where (courseid not in (select courseid from applicants)
)"

);
```

for example :
if i have table newcourses that have these rows

```
courseid   coursename         max applicant
1          English standard   3
2          English advance    2
3          Spanish            4
```

and table applicants have these rows

```
id name  courseid
1  me    1
2  jon   1
3  jake  2
4  sara  2
5  joe   3
```

so how to do so

Comment: Your query doesn't show any record where at least one applicant is in that course. You want to show also the ones that have one applicant only?

Comment: i want if condition to show me the courses that have less than 2 applicant if it have two or more donot want them to show

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must include all negative rows on subquery by using filter like GROUP BY - HAVING.

```
SELECT courseid, coursename
FROM newcourses 
WHERE courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 1)
```

Easier to read:

```
SELECT courseid, coursename
FROM newcourses 
WHERE courseid IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) = 1)
```

Comment: Downvoted for not including any explanation that would be useful for future readers, or even future problems the OP might have.

Comment: so i manage to make it work as i want the final code like this

  $co2 = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];

 


   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  courseid,coursename,datefrom,dateto 
FROM newcourses 
where (courseid not in (select courseid from applicants WHERE (NationalId = $co2) )) AND (courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 2))
");

Comment: my question is can i set the count from a value in the newcourses table for example i add a column called count in the newcourses table and i want the if count take the number from that column

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```sql
SELECT  n.courseid, n.coursename
FROM newcourses n
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON n.courseid = a.courseid
GROUP BY n.courseid, n.coursename
HAVING count(a.id) <=1;
```

This will get all the courses that don't have any applicants and the ones that have one applicant.
And it doesn't use a subquery that has to run once for every record selected, so you gain on performance also.

This uses a LEFT JOIN between newcourses and applicants tables. This shows any element of newcourses that have records in applicants table but shows also the ones that aren't in the applicants table (that's the reason to use LEFT JOIN).

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d55009/1)</kbd>

If you want to check them separately you can do:

### To get the courses with no applicants:

```sql
SELECT  n.courseid, n.coursename
FROM newcourses n
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON n.courseid = a.courseid
GROUP BY n.courseid, n.coursename
HAVING count(a.id) = 0;
```

### To exclude courses with two applicants:

```sql
SELECT  n.courseid, n.coursename
FROM newcourses n
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON n.courseid = a.courseid
GROUP BY n.courseid, n.coursename
HAVING count(a.id) != 2;
```

If you can't have more than two, you can change the `!=` to `<`

---

If you end up adding a new column to newcourses with the max number of applicants, you can't put that in an external HAVING COUNT, so you would have to do a subquery:

```sql
SELECT  n.courseid, n.coursename
FROM newcourses n
LEFT JOIN applicants a ON n.courseid = a.courseid
WHERE n.maxApplicants >= (SELECT count(*) 
                          FROM applicants ap WHERE ap.courseid = n.courseid)
GROUP BY n.courseid, n.coursename
```

Comment: I think MySQL would be able to optimise the sub-query without running it for every row of the result, but this is certainly a tidier solution. It would be nice to explain *how* it works though.

Comment: i want the two condition separated because in the first condition i will add another if let me explain more so my script allow user to join the course once and after that he donot see the course again also i want to check if there are two user in a course the course donot appear to any one else

Comment: @aloyoon Then one of your queries needs to only look at rows for "the current user", although it's not clear how a user is uniquely identified in your DB.

Comment: @aloyoon. To replace your original query you can just use the query i did and change the having count at the end to  `= 0` when you want to show the courses with no applicants. If you want the courses with only one applicant you change it to `= 1` and you can change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

Comment: co i made it like this is there a better way for this to be done 

    $co2 = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT  courseid,coursename,datefrom,dateto 
    FROM newcourses 
    where (courseid not in (select courseid from applicants WHERE (NationalId = $co2) )) AND (courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 2))
");

and can i set the count from a value in the newcourses table for example i add a column called count in the newcourses table and i want the if count take the number from that column

Comment: here is my query now it does what i want but donot know if its the best way 

$co2 = $_SESSION['MM_Username']; $sql=mysql_query("SELECT courseid,coursename,datefrom,dateto FROM newcourses where (courseid not in (select courseid from applicants WHERE (NationalId = $co2) )) AND (courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 2)) ");

can you check it also can i set the count from a value in the newcourses table for example i add a column called count in the newcourses table and i want the if count take the number from that column

Comment: @aloyoon. About the count, if you have a column that has the number of students you don't have to use count(courseid), you just use that column in the where. about improving your query, i'll add an updated query.

Comment: @aloyoon. But you are now doing a HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 2 is this really what you want? exclude the ones that have MORE than 2?

Comment: the column that i want to add in the newcourses will be the max number of user the course can have so if i can make the if count condition read the number i can set different max number for each course

Comment: @aloyoon. I just updated my answer with a query to handle different max for each course.

Comment: @aloyoon. So you ended up using a subquery? Not asking you to accept my answer, but that approach is slower than with a JOIN, and if you want the results from the answer just change the HAVING COUNT of one of my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
$sql = mysql_query( 

   "SELECT  courseid,coursename
   FROM newcourses 
   WHERE (courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING( COUNT( courseid ) > 1)))
   "
);
```

"HAVING (COUNT (courseid) > 1))" will return multiples ocurences values of the table "applicants".

Comment: here is my query now it does what i want but donot know if its the best way 

$co2 = $_SESSION['MM_Username']; $sql=mysql_query("SELECT courseid,coursename,datefrom,dateto FROM newcourses where (courseid not in (select courseid from applicants WHERE (NationalId = $co2) )) AND (courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 2)) ");

can you check it also can i set the count from a value in the newcourses table for example i add a column called count in the newcourses table and i want the if count take the number from that column

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  courseid,coursename
FROM newcourses 
where courseid not in (select courseid from applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid)=2)
```

If you want to ignore courseids which are triplets or more use  `HAVING COUNT(courseid)>1`

Comment: this didnot work it show all the newcourses no matter how many times the courseid are in the applicants table

Comment: Downvoted for not including any explanation that would be useful for future readers, or even future problems the OP might have.

Comment: here is my query now it does what i want but donot know if its the best way 

$co2 = $_SESSION['MM_Username']; $sql=mysql_query("SELECT courseid,coursename,datefrom,dateto FROM newcourses where (courseid not in (select courseid from applicants WHERE (NationalId = $co2) )) AND (courseid NOT IN (SELECT courseid FROM applicants GROUP BY courseid HAVING COUNT(courseid) > 2)) ");

can you check it also can i set the count from a value in the newcourses table for example i add a column called count in the newcourses table and i want the if count take the number from that column